# C Read from File will always read 0 bytes

Tags: c, file, buffer, fopen

I got this problem where i want to read from file using read function, but i cant't. 
My code does that. I have a parent proccess and a child process. The child does an exec command and i have redirected the stdout to a file f. The parent waits the child and after that is reads from the file it's content and stores it to a buffer. Then i'm sending this output to a client through socket,using send, but that's not the problem. The problem is that even though the txt has content inside from the exec command, read function won't read anything and from my testing it always reads 0 bytes.

```
                 //parent

                    if (wait(&status2)== -1){ // Wait for child
                        perror("wait");
                    }

                    check_child_exit(status2);

                    n = read(f, buffer, MAX_BUFF-1);
                    if (n < 0){
                        error("ERROR reading from File");
                    }    
                    printf("\n%d\n",n);

                    n = send(newsockfd,buffer, MAX_BUFF-1,0);
                    if (n < 0){
                        perror("ERROR writing to socket");
                        break;
                    }


               //child
                     dup2(f,1);
                     dup2(f,2);
                        .
                        .
                        .

                     execvp(words[0],words); // Execute date
                     perror("execvp");
                     exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
```

So as you can see these are the 2 processes. I heard from another article that the problem might be on the opening of the file. But im not sure which options to use or not. I even tried to open with open function and fopen function just to try new things.
Here are the open and fopen call:

```
        f = open("temp133",O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,0755);
        if (f==-1){
            error_exit("Error Exit");

        }

        FILE *fd=fopen("tmp","w+");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If `read` returns `0` it means end-of-file. What data is there in the file? The `open` call you show creates a brand new and *empty* file.

Comment: yes but the child process will put date into the text file for sure. I had also opened the files to see what's inside. And it's the output of the child process and especially the exec command

Comment: if you get what im doing, is i wait for the child process to write something in the file and then from the parent process i read that file that the child has already written

Comment: Then think about ordering. And about flushing buffers and synchronizing the disks and such, to make sure that the contents is really written. And in the parent process where you attempt to read the contents, seek to the beginning to reset and refresh the file in that process.

Comment: By the way, what are you trying to do? Can't you open a pipe for the child process to write to and the parent process to read from? Do the communication have to happen through a file? Will the file be kept and used later?

Comment: hmm i think that i already do that by waiting for the child process to finish. But furthermore i will try as you send to read from the begging ...

Comment: so my plan was to just redirect the output to the socket and that's all, hoping that the output will go to the client. But on the client side im using a recv command and a lot of time the output from he server, using just a redirection only with dup2, was coming into packages. So form the client side the recv command after the first "package" it was leaving the recv command. So i thought to write all the output to a file and then send the whole file to the client. Each time i will cleaning the contents of the file... that was my thought. What was your idea with pipes??

Comment: Don't need a file or even a pipe if you just want to send the child's output to the socket. Just make the the socket the child's STDOUT, and write directly to the STDOUT and thus the socket in the child

Comment: Yeah that was my idea from the begging. But some times that let's say i wanted to print from child to client, two "packages" of text. Let's say 2 printf's , the problem was that from the client's side that the recv commans would read the first package(printf) but the second one would stay into the socket buffer and then in the next loop i would pop, Which i didn't like that